# Achart engine - How to display the Pie chart legends to center

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using Achart Engine to display the pie chart, now i see that the legends are not displaying to the center.

i want the legends to be displayed in center how to do it?

Comment: Do you want it centered on the X axis or the Y axis?

Comment: @Dan hello dan how are you, i want it to center of x axis, now it is towards left end , i just want to be to positioned to center

Comment: Not possible with ACE out of the box.

Comment: @Dan can you please help me in acheiving that by editing the source code? because i see many people asking for this. it will help others also

Answer (score 1):

As stated by many questions and answers out there the legend cannot be centered for achartengine. I was actually looking for it myself.

The only solution i have herd of is to hid the current one and then display a new one in a text view.